# Java & openGL issue. GL_POINTS

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have the following code:

```
public void draw() {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(50, 50);
            glVertex2i(100, 100);
        glEnd();
    }
```

which is init'ed by:

```
public void glinit(){
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
```

All works fine, and I get the line exactly where I want it to be. Problem that I am having is that I do not want a line, I want to display pixels. I used the code:

```
public void draw() {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(50, 50);
    glEnd();
}
```

thinking this would work with no issues, but nothing is being rendered to the screen.  I tried to increase the glPointSize(6.0f) just to debug, but I still get nothing being rendered. Any insights?

And before anyone asks, yes I am calling the glClear(GL_CLEAR_BUFFER_BIT) in the main render class :)

Comment: Where did you dig up `GL_CLEAR_BUFFER_BIT`?  Maybe you're thinking of `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`?

Comment: "I tried to increase the glPointSize(6.0f) just to debug"...did you call `glPointSize()` *before* the `glBegin()/glEnd()` pair?  Or inside?

Comment: One possible issue comes to mind: If after vertex transformation, object-space <50, 50> is outside of your window then the entire point will be clipped and nothing will be drawn; even if the point size is wide enough that at least part of it would be visible. Are you using a ModelView matrix, or is it identity?

Comment: Thanks for responces, @genpfault: sorry yes, GL_COLOR BUFFER_BIT my apologies. The glPointSize is inside the glBegin - glEnd

Comment: @Andon: my window is 800x600 so 50, 50 is well within. and I am using a ModelView matrix

Comment: One question, what is wrong with my post? Why is there a -1 on it????

Comment: <50,50> is the point before your model view matrix and projection matrices transform it into clip space. So your window size really has nothing to do with anything when you use a non-identity model view matrix.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman ok thanks, I will bear that in mind. Would this also stop the GL_LINES from being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little quad with glVertex2i(50, 50); glVertex2i(51, 50); glVertex2i(51, 51); glVertex2i(50, 51);